# How to create a Firebase Cloud Function for a Document Created on a Collection inside of another Document and Collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a question with CloudFunctions, I need to create a function on Create of a document inside Firestore.

The problem that I have is the way the data is set up:

[image: Data Base Set up]

So I have a Collection called Chat Rooms which gets documents that will vary, and inside each document, you will have some fields and another subcollection, and inside that subcollection already the thing that I need to get on the function.

The problem that I have is that this function should be aware or access with every document created:

Somehting like:

```
exports.ChatSent = functions.firestore.document('chatrooms/{Variable part}/chats').onCreate((snap, ctx) => { print('do whatever'); return;});
```

The problem is I don't know how to write that variable part as this function should be executed whenever a new document is written on the ***Chats*** collection of each one of the documents inside the Chatroom collection.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use twice a [wildcard when defining the path](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#wildcards-parameters), as follows:

```
exports.ChatSent = functions.firestore.document('chatrooms/{chatroomId}/chats/{chatId}').onCreate((snap, ctx) => {

 print('do whatever');
 return null;

});
```

If you need to get the wildcards values, do as follows:

```
exports.ChatSent = functions.firestore.document('chatrooms/{chatroomId}/chats/{chatId}').onCreate((snap, ctx) => {

 const chatroomId = ctx.params.chatroomId;
 const chatId = ctx.params.chatId;`

 print('do whatever');
 return null;

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much just what I need it.

Comment: Gladly Thank you